# How to remove "Java support" from NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to uninstall only the Java portion of NetBeans because I don't need it anymore. How do I remove it without removing other packages (php, c/c++, etc)?

Comment: Sorry didn't mention. Version 7.0.1.

Comment: You can disable the Java package, but you can't really remove as it's the foundation of NetBeans. Remember, NetBeans is a JAVA application and that a lot of the editing support is actually part of the Java modules. Why do you need to uninstall it though? Perhaps your are trying to do something we do not understand?

Comment: I actually installed the full package of netbeans 7.0.1 ( shouldn't have). I don't even do anything in java, mainly php. I've noticed a lot of functionalities in the menus are Java too, so might as well make things simple and get rid of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on Tools->Plugins and navigate on installed plugins tab. Once there filter your installed plugins using "Search" functionality. YOu can search for "java".

In the filtered list you can start disabling the plugins you dont need